# Insert columns, within a range, based on cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, named-ranges

So am trying to tell VBA to insert a certain number of columns between two other columsn based on a cell reference.

I've managed to get excel to insert columns within my range:

> Sub INSERT()
>
> Range(Range("Data_FirstColumn").Offset(, 1)Range("Data_Net").Offset(, -2)).EntireColumn.INSERT
>
> End Sub

Essentially I want to insert x number of columns between "Data_FirstColumn" and "Data_Net" based on a cell reference

EG: If the cell say 10, I want excel to insert 10 columns between "Data_FirstColumn" and "Data_Net". If the cell says 1, I want excel to insert 1 column between "Data_FirstColumn" and "Data_Net".

I've tried the following, but it keeps inserting columns to the left of "Data_FirstColumn", not between "Data_FirstColumn" and "Data_Net"

```
Sub INSERT()
Range(Range("Data_FirstColumn").Offset(, 1), Range("Data_Boundary").Offset(, -2)).Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("Assumptions!B26").Value
    Columns(1).INSERT
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just something simple like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A1").Value

    Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i
End Sub
```

so for yours, using a named range, just throw in the `shift:=xltoright` and it will shift that column to the right, inserting the new one to the left of it.